# Java: turn List<String> into input for method(String, String, String)

Tags: java, string, list, methods, input

Hope the title is explanatory.

```
 1 public void commander(){
 2  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
 3  System.out.println("\nWelcome to my application."
 4          + "\nType the command you want to use,"
 5          + "or type 'exit' to close the program.");
 6  while (input.next() != "exit") {
 7      List<String> userInput = Arrays.asList(input.next().split(" "));
 8      Class<? extends RunnableCommand> command = Commands.commandsMap().get(userInput.get(0));
 9      userInput.remove(0);
10      // command.run(userInput); ?!
11  }
```

**Line  8:** RunnableCommand is an interface that provides the run() method, implemented by every Class that represents a command (inspired by *policy pattern*).

**Line 10:** Here's the problem. The run() method of every "command class" can have 1, 2 or 3 String(s) as input.

Is there a way to give every element of **userInput** as input for the **run()** method?

Comment: `input.next() != "exit"` -> [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: Also `next` can return only one token so `next().split(" ")` has no sense. You may be interested in `nextLine`.

Comment: `input.next() != "exit"` is not going to work the way you (probably) expect it to. Try `!"exit".equals(input.next())`.

Comment: Thank you all, these were all things that I totally needed to know.

Comment: What is signature of `run` method (what arguments it expect)? Is it `run(String arg1, String arg2, String arg3)` or `run(String[] arguments)` or `run(String... arguments)` or maybe even instead of String you are using `Object`?

Comment: Why not modify the `run()` method to accept a List<String>? And as @Pshemo and @f_puras have pointed out, that sort of spring isn't probably what you want. Take a look at this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/java-string-equals-versus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement run method like this:

```
public void run(String... commands) {
  ...
}
```

You can call it by passing an array or comma separate parameters.

```
command.run(input1);
command.run(input1, input2);
command.run(input1, input2, input3);
```

or

```
command.run(userInput.toArray(new String[0]);
```